# the Rearrange fields and groups option disappreace from content type management section

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, cck

i know it is not a program related issue but let me ask it here.

i don't know what does happen to 'Rearrange fields and groups' in content type management.
when i click on manage fields link to rearrange fields i don't see that X anchor. instead i see a new column with the name of weight.
i don't want this weight column,it is hard to arrange fields with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript is either not loading or choking up at some point, try clearing all caches and stuff to see if that does anything.

Otherwise you might have to procedurally debug to find what is causing the js to error out.

Comment: thanks Antonio i will try it,but why that weight column is apprease?

Comment: it is solved now,it was because of enabling theme developer module.thanks again Antonio.